# Laravel: @if Auth::user()->email and checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, laravel

**EDIT: Laravel has a build in remember me function. Even when the user does not check the checkbox it keeps you signed in for 2 hours. If you do press the checkbox it remembers you for 5 years**

I am making a simple login system in Laravel. I want to add a remember me function when the users clicks a checkbox. Currently I have an automated function which checks if the user has successfully logged in. But now I would like to make it that the user also has to check the checkbox.

this is my code now which works without a checkbox

```
 @if(isset(Auth::user()->email))
        <script>window.location="/main/succeslogin";</script>
 @endif
```

this is my form where I already added the checkbox

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/main/checklogin') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Enter Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Enter Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"/>
            <label>Remember me</label>

        </div>
    </form>
```

now this is what I have tried :

```
  @if(isset(Auth::user()->email) AND isset($_POST['remember']))
        <script>window.location="/main/succeslogin";</script>
    @endif
```

Let me explain what happened without the checkbox. When the user logged in and tried to visit the login page again. It automatically loaded the /succeslogin page because the user was logged in already.. Now I only want that to happen when the user checked the checkbox. With your code the logged in user can still visit the login page.

Comment: Where you're trying it? in blade file or controller? `<script>window.location="/main/succeslogin";</script>`

Comment: this is in login.blade ..sorry

Comment: Check it, please - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: But this part of the code is working its the if statment wich is not working

Comment: @Dmitry That is working for me.. My code does remember users but I want it to only remeber users after they clicked a checkbox

Comment: I recommend you to use `&&` instead of `AND` in your conditionals.

Comment: Why not use the default Auth login? That would handle all of this for you.

Comment: I also tried it with && didnt work @Chemaclass

Comment: Because I want to login using my own database @Qirel

Comment: ...but you can still use your own database even if you use the default Laravel Auth. No need to reinvent the wheel! :-)

Comment: Can you link me a good tutorial I can follow for that? because I have never used the default auth login before

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Auth::user()` if the user has not logged in. `Auth::user()` is used to get the currently authenticated user.

Just get input from the request.

```
@if(request()->input('email') AND request()->input('remember'))

   // todo..

@endif
```

---

#### Update (based on comments)

Default Laravel have `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware to keep an already authenticated user from reaching the login or registration routes/views since they're already logged in.

```
Auth::routes();
```

Or for custom route, you can use `guest` :

```
Route::get('your-login-page-or-another-route', 'LoginController@method')
    ->middleware('guest');
```

---

If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the `attempt` method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout. Your `users` table must include the string `remember_token` column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

Comment: This sadly does not work.. Let me explain what happend without the checkbox. When the user loged in and tried to visit the login page again. It automaticly loaded the /succeslogin page because the user was logged in already.. Now I only want that to happen when the user checked the checkbox. With your code the logged in user can still visit the login page.

Comment: You should explain it to your question too. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question with this explanation

Comment: @AboveTheLaw check my answer

Comment: where should I put this code and where does it check if he user checked the checkbox?

Comment: Put it on your routes. Do you use the default auth route on laravel?

Comment: I think so I use the /routes/web.php

Comment: I did put it in my routes but It still did not work it never checks if the user checked the checkbox or not.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this code what do you want:

```
@if(Auth::user()->email && Auth::viaRemember())
    <script>window.location="/main/succeslogin";</script>
@endif
```

Comment: you forgot one ) on the end of your code. But this code gives me this error 'Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)'